# Prototype used to store an object not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript

I want to create a settings object on the prototype chain which acts as a lookup for my application. I've tried this:

http://jsfiddle.net/7kwXd/3/

```
var d9l = {};

d9l.aMethod = function() {
    //fails here with Cannot read property 'dimension1' of undefined 
    alert(this.anObject.dimension1);
};

d9l.aMethod.prototype.anObject = {
   dimension1 : "x1",
   dimension2 : "y1"
};

var testing = d9l.aMethod();
```

But I just get ***Cannot read property 'dimension1' of undefined*** in the constructor. Is it not possible to define a prototype as an object?

Comment: That only works with constructors.

Comment: When called via `d9l.aMethod()`, the `this` value in `d9l.aMethod` is the object `d91`, **not** the function itself.  Also, `prototype` is only used when you are using `new` with your functions, using them as constructors.

Comment: The anObject doesn't seem to have access to this - http://jsfiddle.net/7kwXd/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `d9l` is not a contructed object, its methods don't refer to `this` as you might expect. To verify, try `alert(this)` and see what you get.

To fix, do this:

```
function d9l() {}
d9l.prototype.aMethod = function() {
    alert(this.anObject.dimension1);
};
d9l.prototype.anObject = {
    dimension1: "x1",
    dimension2: "y1"
};
var testing = (new d9l()).aMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

The prototype property only works on constructor functions (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7kwXd/2/) :

```
var Ctor = function(){
}

Ctor.prototype = {
    aMethod:function(){
        alert(this.anObject.dimension1);
    },
    anObject:{
        dimension1 : "x1",
        dimension2 : "y1"
    }
}


var d9l = new Ctor();

var testing = d9l.aMethod();
```

This is a very good article about how protos work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff852808.aspx